# Java beginner regarding repetition

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner and I'm trying to follow the logic behind this code snippet.

```
int x = 12;
do {
    for (int w=9; w<x; w++)
        System.out.print(w+” ”);
    --x;
    System.out.println(x);
}while (x>7);
```

When I run it, the answer is as follows:

```
9 10 11 11
9 10 10
9 9
8
7
```

If someone could explain how to read the code step by step in a simple way I would be very happy!

Comment: May be you should read a java tutorial, you'll get to understand the basics for looping clearly.

Comment: Run this code on Eclipse or NetBeans step by step, watch variable changes. Probably this is the most I could advice

Comment: You should use debugger in an IDE. Chceck [this](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/) link for easy description how to do it in eclipse. Set breakpoint on first line, and then go line by line and observe how variables change. It is a great way to learn!

Comment: Do you think that someone just starting with java is using an ide and used to step-debugging?

Comment: I have added a link with easy-to-follow description how to run ide + debugger

Comment: Eclipse is not a good way to learn java! You won't understand anything about java if you start with eclipse...

Comment: @Chris What bad can happen when You look how program works step by step?

Comment: ... running your code in a debugger is a good way to understand what each line does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int x = 12;` declare new local variable, called `x`

`do {` begins new `do...while` loop

`for (int w=9; w<x; w++)` begins new `for` loop which will iterate until value of variable `w` is **less** then value of variable `x`. After each iteration of this loop variable `w` will increase its value (by `w++`). Initial value of variable `w` is `9` (`int w=9`).

`System.out.print(w+” ”);` this one prints out to console current value of variable `w` plus one white-space after that

`--x;` this one decreases value of `x` variable. It is such called prefix version of operation `--`

`System.out.println(x);` prints value of `x` variable to console and returns carriage

<strike>`}` end of `for` loop code block</strike> (fixed thanks to Chris)

`} while (x>7);` end of `while` code block with condition on which loop will end: until value of variable `x` is more then `7` loop will run.

**UPD:** More specifically explaining output result:

1) 1-st iteration of `do loop`. We have `x == 12`:

iterations of internal `for` loop:

1.1) `w == 9` , `9 < 12` => outputs `9` to console

1.2) `w++` => `w == 10`, `10 < 12` => outputs `10` to console,

1.3) `w++` => `w == 11`, `11 < 12` => outputs `11` to console,

1.4) `w++` => `w == 12`, `12 == 12` => ends `for` loop

2) `for` loop ends. `--x` => `x == 11` , outputs `11` to console and returns carriage, so we have line `9 10 11 11`

3) begins new iteration of `do ... while` loop with `x == 11` and so on until `x` became equals to 7.

Comment: } does not end for loop. It end the do-loop because there is no starting { for the for loop.

Comment: @Chris ups, agree, will fix

Answer (score 0):

First of all, proper formatting of the snippet would help you understand it :)

```
int x = 12;
do {
    for (int w=9; w<x; w++)
        System.out.print(w+” ”);
    --x;
    System.out.println(x);
} while (x>7);
```

It's hard to describe it in a step by step way, it's better to run using debugger for it. But in other words, the program is following:

1. there is do-while loop which has internal 'for' loop, decrement x
   and print it
2. the for loop works with w variable and print it. The
   condition depends on x value (I think, you understand how conditions
   work etc.)
3. in for loop, 'print' methods is used, as opposite to
   'println' in do-while loop. That's why w values are printed in a
   line

Answer (score 0):

The do/while loop runs if x is greater than 7. The for loop runs inside of the do/while loop. The for loop declares an integer w and assigns w the value of 9. w